# Why is this Comments Regex wrong?

Tags: regex, comments

> "/* "[^* /]* "* /"

It matches the first /* then it waits for any character except for the */, and then when it gets the */ it will match the entire regex, but for this comment for example:

> /*bruno / braga */

Can someone tell me why the / dont match?
Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, you forgot that `*` is a special character and must be escaped to match a literal. Try using `/\*(?:(?!\*/|/\*)[\s\S])*\*/`, or simpler `/\*[\s\S]*?\*/`. IF you do not have newline symbols in the comments, try using `/\*.*?\*/`.

Comment: If any of the regexps work for you, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this Comments Regex wrong?

It's due to a few issues with the regex:

1. all the unnecessary quotes `"` inside it
2. when you start a character class with a negation sign: `[^]` it negates everything in it, in your example it will negate space as well cause you've included it in. Further, the character `/` exists in the middle of the input-string and you probably want to disallow it only when it follows `*` in the context of "ending the comment" - `*/`.
3. as stribizhev already mentioned in the comments above - `*` is a special character and should be escaped. Same applies for `/`
4. The space that exists in the regex right after `/*` (the input string `/*bruno...` doesn't contain such a space)
5. The space between the last star and the slash that closes the comment: `* /`

Summing up all the points above, the regex should be corrected to:

```
\/\*[^\*]*\*\/
```

See [**DEMO**](http://www.regexr.com/3bqee)

---

Following up on Luis's comment: if you want to allow `*` symbol inside the comment, you can use:

```
\/\*(.*?)\*\/
```

See **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oY0dW8/2)**

Comment: @LuisColorado true, but there was no such requirement. If the OP thinks that a `*` symbol is likely to be part of the comment - this requirement should be added to the question :)

Comment: But it's supposed he will want to get a correct answer, not dealing again with the problem when he sees that including a `*` invalidates the whole matching string.  Even if it has not been specified as such, a C language comment allows putting `*` chars inside.

Comment: That edit will make it accept `/* bla bla */ /* bla bla */' as a whole comment, not as two comments with a space in between.  Have a look at my solution, as I have answerted this question also.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the `?` in the end of the group.  The mistake is mine.

Answer (score 0):

A correct regex to match a comment (allowing everything inside but a `*/` sequence, you must first allow any character except a `*`, or a `*` followed by anything but a `/`, so

```
/\*([^\*]|\*[^/])*\*/
```

See [Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/kV5sL6/1)

should do the work (remember that in demonstration regexp delimiters are `/` so they are escaped with backslashes, perhaps you'll have to do that to escape in your code.